# Losing network connectivity after anniversary update

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, windows-10-v1607

Ever since the Windows 10 anniversary update installed on my computer, I will randomly lose network connectivity.

This happens about once per day. I am confident that it is the PC and not the network. Other devices still have connectivity.

The system tray icon will say that I have a connection, but sites will not load and a ping to Google won't work.

Every time that I lose connectivity, it is always accompanied by Disk usage being spiked at 100% by "Service Host: Local System (Network Restricted)".

Restarting the system always restores network connectivity. Sometimes the issue resolves itself after a few minutes. When the Disk usage returns to a normal level, network connectivity returns.

Can anyone confirm these two issues are related? If so, does anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important:
Instead of rebooting you can do this :

```
Windows-Logo-Taste + R -> cmd
ipconfig /flushdns   
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

As batch:

```
@echo off
set "host=google.com"

:loop
ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo Success.
) else (
    ipconfig /flushdns 
    ipconfig /release
    ipconfig /renew
)
timeout /T 100
goto loop
```

1.On the assumption that the error is due to a driver compatibility problem with Windows 10, I would recommend deactivating outsourcing functions like "offload".

[Disable Offload](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951037)

2.There are reports that the Windows performs prefetch function to an unusual high utilization of the svchost service, but i have not enough information to confirm this .

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters

    0 – Disables Prefetcher    <-------
    1 – Enables Prefetch for Applications only
    2 – Enables Prefetch for Boot files only
    3 – Enables Prefetch for Boot and Application files
```

3.Does the DNS service work correctly.
Try:

```
ping 216.58.214.78
```

instead of

```
ping google.com
```

Comment: Thank you - these 3cmd w/o reboot helped me too! Any idea for a change that will help to avoid this issue in the future - or is the best cure to save these 3 in a batch-file?

Comment: Of course since I posted this question, I haven't encountered the problem.  This all looks like good info though. I'll go ahead and mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same problem here in company with many machines. We've tried to perform various procedures, but only one is ahead. Try to restore the windows to the day before the 10th, it decided on some machines, but most of what we have here is with the disabled system recovery on windows 10.